# How to stop UnknownHostException in android

Tags: java, android

Let me tell you a bit about my app, when the app is in the background, I send some session data to my `session_endpoint` first, and if sending is failed, I get the exception that the host is unknown from try/catch and send it to same host, which is for sending exceptions `exception_endpoint`.

So my question is, how is it possible that I can send data to my `exception_endpoint` and cannot send to `session_endpoint`, is it about resolving domain ? sending methods are the same by the way. I lose my precious session data. How can I overcome this issue ?

I get java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host.

Comment: You should probably queue the exceptions and send them when the network is available.

Comment: @kichik, I queue the session data, but the problem is not that, I can send one payload and cannot send the other, with same domains.

Comment: your end point might not be working

Comment: @TabishHussain come on

Answer (score 0):

There are several options how you can handle that exception. The simplest way is to cache the requests and fire them on the next app start.

You could also use the alarm manager to try it later or maybe even better use the [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), there you can define that you require network connectivity. If you need to support older platforms try the nice lib [Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job). There you can define for much more platforms the scheduling.

Comment: The problem is that, I can send the second request, the first request gets the unnownhost exception sometimes, the second one does not get the exception.

Comment: That are network issues in general. Retry is the only real option IMHO.